# ¿Cómo centrar texto en PyQt ComboBox?

Tags: python, pyqt5, interfaz-gráfica

He creado una tabla donde todos sus ítems los he conseguido centrar, excepto los ComboBox, he intentado con algunos métodos de QtCore sin éxito, ¿hay alguna forma?

Nota: El item **c1** de la función **mas**, es el combo box.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QComboBox, QTableWidgetItem, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
class SubwindowDatosEntrada(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, root=None):

    def mas(self):
        nuevo = self.table_datosEntrada.rowCount()
        self.table_datosEntrada.insertRow(nuevo)

        for row in range(self.table_datosEntrada.rowCount() - 1, 
            self.table_datosEntrada.rowCount(), 1):
            for rowe in range(self.table_datosEntrada.columnCount()):

                #Combo Box
                c1 = QComboBox()
                c1.lineEdit().setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
                c1.addItems(['Casa', 'Vivienda'])

                # Números en celdas centradas                 
                item = QTableWidgetItem(str(self.table_datosEntrada.rowCount()))
                itemb = QTableWidgetItem()
                item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
                itemb.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)                

                self.table_datosEntrada.setCellWidget(row, 1, c1)
                self.table_datosEntrada.setCellWidget(row, 12, c2)
                self.table_datosEntrada.setItem(row, 0, item)
                self.table_datosEntrada.setItem(row, rowe, itemb)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = SubwindowDatosEntrada()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu idea es buena excepto por un detalle, traducido y adaptado de la [documentación oficial](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#lineEdit):

### `QComboBox.lineEdit() -> QLineEdit`

> Retorna el QLineEdit usado para editar items en el combobox o `None`
>   si no hay QLineEdit.
>
> **Solo comboboxs editables tienen `QLineEdit`.**

Podrías hacer por tanto:

```
c1 = QComboBox()
c1.addItems(['Casa', 'Vivienda'])
c1.setEditable(True)
c1.lineEdit().setReadOnly(True)
c1.lineEdit().setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
for i in range(c1.count()):
    c1.setItemData(i, Qt.AlignCenter, Qt.TextAlignmentRole)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu aporte, es justo lo que estaba intentando hacer. Saludos cordiales.